# How to get_fields() the translated values in the custom post type?

Tags: php, wordpress, translation, advanced-custom-fields, custom-fields

I used the *wp Multilang* plugin to translate a custom post type that has custom fields.

The plugin offers me filling the custom fields in two languages [English and Arabic] and now I have the post type with the same id but with different URLs like this:

```
http://website.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=2654&action=edit&edit_lang=en
http://website.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=2654&action=edit&edit_lang=ar
```

[image: as it appears I have two buttons in the post type edit page. both show the post type but with different language so how can I retrieve this in the code]

please help.

Comment: I don't found the wplang plugin. where do you find it ?

Comment: Hi Kaperto now i changed it to wp multilang

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-multilang/                   actually if get_fields() always returns the default language translation of the plugin and i can change the default on the code before calling get_fields()

Answer (score 0):

actually i just needed to add ?edit_lang=en to my request so he detects another language 
so you can set any language you want like this if it is at the backend side.